# JavaScript calculation error above 100

Tags: javascript

I have a function which checks a number(quantity) against an array of `quantity range: price`

```js
var data = {
  "1 - 4": " $4.25 ",
  "10 - 24": " $3.25 ",
  "25 - 49": " $3.04 ",
  "5 - 9": " $3.51 ",
  "50+": " $2.84 "
}

function get_price(arr, val) {
  var price = Object.keys(arr).reduce((a, c) => {
    var s = c.trim();
    if (/\d+\-\d+/.test(s)) {
      var range = s.split("-");
      if (val >= parseInt(range[0]) && val <= parseInt(range[1])) {
        a = arr[c];
      }
    } else {
      s = s.replace(/\D/g, "");
      if (val >= s) {
        a = arr[c];
      }
    }
    return a;
  }, 0);
  return price;
}
```

The problem is that if a number is greater then 50 but less then 100 it is calculating correctly, over 100 it is not able to see the 50+ and use that price.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: mind you `arr` is an object not an array!

Comment: Just poor variable naming.

Comment: @Alex not *just*: `And the example array`

Comment: @Ivan yup, I lol'ed when I seen it :)

Comment: Works fine for me when I try this in the console.

Comment: OP, give example inputs too, not just the array.

Comment: Vouch for @Jerodev, tested it on Fiddle, it works.

Comment: This looks like an issue in comparing Strings, not Numbers.

Comment: @Alex,Ivan LOL you guys are awsome.point to point

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, this code has changed from its initial purpose so excuse the naming conventions

Comment: You do not convert it to a number in the else

Comment: "so excuse the naming conventions": Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use strings as your objects' keys, that will work fine:

```
const range = {
  "1-4": " $4.25 ",
  "10-24": " $3.25 ",
  "25-49": " $3.04 ",
  "5-9": " $3.51 ",
  "50+": " $2.84 "
}
```

More about [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

> In this code, property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore (`"_"`) and dollar sign (`"$"`), that cannot start with a number. For example, `object.$1` is valid, while `object.1` is not.
>
> - [MDN Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org)

Demo:

```js
function get_price(arr, val) {
  var price = Object.keys(arr).reduce((a, c) => {
    var s = c.trim();
    if (/\d+\-\d+/.test(s)) {
      var range = s.split("-");
      if (val >= parseInt(range[0]) && val <= parseInt(range[1])) {
        a = arr[c];
      }
    } else {
      s = s.replace(/\D/g, "");
      if (val >= s) {
        a = arr[c];
      }
    }
    return a;
  }, 0);
  return price;
}

const range = {
  "1-4": " $4.25 ",
  "10-24": " $3.25 ",
  "25-49": " $3.04 ",
  "5-9": " $3.51 ",
  "50+": " $2.84 "
}

console.log(get_price(range, 60))
console.log(get_price(range, 500))
```

Comment: OP says it doesn't work for numbers over 100. It does for me though, but maybe change your example?

Comment: Just added a test case for anything over `100` as per `over 100 it is not able to see the 50+ and use that price.`. Waiting for peer review

Comment: Works fine as it should.

Comment: Sorry @Alex for the refused edit, I didn't read OP wanted above `100`. It works fine

Comment: @Ivan +1  for you guy

Comment: Thank you, I've added documentation to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Comment: @Ivan Thanks so much for the insight! Solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not work only if you pass strings as the `val` parameter to the `get_price` as it will do string comparison between lets say `"100" > "50"` and it will fail.

Convert to numbers to be sure

```
if (+val >= +s) {
    a = arr[c];
}
```

and

```
if (+val >= parseInt(range[0]) && +val <= parseInt(range[1])) {
    a = arr[c];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat different approach.  I'm assuming that the ranges list is likely to get reused.  This solution uses a function that turns, say `'25 - 49'`, into `{start: 25, end: 49}`, and uses it to create an array of objects such as `{start: 25, end: 49, value: '$3.04'}`.  Then I return a function closing over this array that accepts a price and return the value of the first range which includes this price.

This has the (probably minor) advantage of not continually parsing the range strings.  More importantly, it breaks the problem into several reusable pieces.  `makeRange` might be reused elsewhere in a project, and so might `findByRange`.  The only part of this specific to the current needs is `getPrice`, and that becomes fairly declarative.

```js
const makeRange = (desc, match = '') => 
  ((match = desc.match(/(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+)/)) && match && {start: Number(match[1]), end: Number(match[2])})
    || ((match = desc.match(/(\d+)\s*\+/)) && match && {start: Number(match[1]), end: Infinity})
    || ((match = desc.match(/<\s*(\d+)/)) && match && {start: -Infinity, end: Number(match[1]) - 1})
    || {start: NaN, end: NaN}


const findByRange = rangeValues => {
  const ranges = Object.keys(rangeValues).map(
    key => Object.assign({value: rangeValues[key]}, makeRange(key))
  ).sort((a, b) => a.start - b.start) // sorting mostly for cleanliness
  
  return val => {
    const range = ranges.find(range => range.start <= val && val <= range.end)
    return range ? range.value : false // or throw an exception, or use default
  }
}


const getPrice = findByRange({
  '< 5'    : ' $4.25 ',  // could also be '1 - 4'
  '5-9'    : ' $3.51 ',
  '10-24'  : ' $3.25 ',
  '25-49'  : ' $3.04 ',
  '50+'    : ' $2.84 '
});

[3, 7, 16, 42, 57, 143].forEach(
  n => console.log(`${n} --> ${getPrice(n)}`)
)
```